# Formatting an integer into a specific string format

Tags: vb6, string-formatting, number-formatting

I was wondering of there was a way of formatting an integer (789) into a string value (7.8.9).

Here is what I am currently doing to format the number:

```
Dim i as integer
Dim s as String
i = 789

s = Left(i, 1) & "." & Mid(i, 2, 1) & "." & Right(i, 1)
```

Note: The integer value will always be a 3 digit number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As String

i = 789
s = Format$(i, "0\.0\.0")
```